# Will Arma 3 work with Linux through Steam Play?

Tags: linux, arma-3, steam-play

I really want to get Arma 3, but I am using Linux. Arma 3 is officially only available on Windows. Will this work with Linux via Steam Play?

Answer (score 2):

[Obviously this will depend on what Distribution you're using and your computer, but it should work without any issues if you're using Proton (Steam Play) version 5.13-5 or above.](https://www.protondb.com/app/107410)